# How to process file names with variables from a list in a file in Bash

Tags: linux, bash

I have a file "FileList.txt" with this text:

```
/home/myusername/file1.txt
~/file2.txt
${HOME}/file3.txt
```

All 3 files exist in my home directory.  I want to process each file in the list from a bash script.  Here is a simplified example:

```
LIST=`cat FileList.txt`
for file in $LIST
do
  echo $file
  ls $file
done
```

When I run the script, I get this output:

```
/home/myusername/file1.txt
/home/myusername/file1.txt
~/file2.txt
ls: ~/file2.txt: No such file or directory
${HOME}/file3.txt
ls: ${HOME}/file3.txt: No such file or directory
```

As you can see, file1.txt works fine.  But the other 2 files do not work.  I think it is because the "${HOME}" variable does not get resolved to "/home/myusername/".  I have tried lots of things with no success, does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks,

-Ben

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `eval`:

```
while read file ; do
  eval echo $file
  eval ls $file
done < FileList.txt
```

From the `bash` manpage regarding the `eval` command:

> The args are read and concatenated together into a single command.  This  command  is
>   then  read and executed by the shell, and its exit status is returned as the value of
>   `eval`.  If there are no args, or only null arguments, `eval` returns 0.

Answer (score 3):

you will hit "spaces problem" using the for loop with cat. Manipulate IFS, or use a while read loop instead

```
while read -r line; do eval ls "$line"; done < file
```

Comment: +1 That is a better approach to reading the file...  I've updated my answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

Change "ls $file" to "eval ls $file" to get the shell to do its expansion.